# VBA to Update a file path for linked Excel work books

Tags: excel, vba

I have a big file that summarizes several workbooks, with the links in the summary file getting updated every month.[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuobD.png)

[image]

Every month, the only thing that changes in the file path is the date. for example, I need to change all cells from "WE 1.27.19" to "WE 2.24.19". Using find and replace, I get prompted to change cells INDIVIDUALLY by going into my company's share drive and clicking on the new file.

[image]

Is there a macro that will automate this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place this kind of question. Once you have started writing your macro, come back and we will help you.

Comment: Ok I have attempted to research VBA, but I'm new to it, So it's hard to understand what I'm doing

Comment: Start by recording a macro. Read and try to understand every line of code.

Answer (score 0):

If the master file never changes, perhaps:

```
Sub UpdateSomeLinks()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rngLinks As Range
Dim strDate As String

'sets variables
Set wb = myworkbook
Set ws = wb.Worksheets("myworksheet")
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

'input box for date
strDate = InputBox("Please type in new date")

'only loops through formula cells
For Each rngLinks In ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    rngLinks.Formula = Replace(rngLinks.Formula, "olddate", strDate)
Next rngLinks

'cleanup
Set ws = Nothing: Set wb = Nothing
Set rngLinks = Nothing: Set fs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then, maybe a button on the Worksheet that calls the above Sub.